# selectInput() in Shiny R not returning any values

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to develop a Shiny app, a simple one. My intention at this point is to create a table and filter that table by various inputs.
Right now this is my code:

```
library("shiny")
library("gapminder")
library("ggplot2")
library("colourpicker")
library("plotly")

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Demo"),
  sliderInput(inputId = "valor", label = "Rango ",
              min = min(data$value), max = max(data$value),
              value = c(min(data$value), max(data$value))),
  selectInput(inputId = "opc", label = "Measurements", choices = levels(data$measurement)),
  
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data <- data
    data <- subset(
      data,
      value >= input$valor[1] & value <= input$valor[2]
    )
    data <- subset(
      data,
      measurement == input$opc
    )
    data
  })
}

levels(data$measurement)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

as you can see, very simple. However, this code returns the table empty and the selectInput with no options of selection. However, if I put the values of the column by hand, the code works fine!

```
selectInput(inputId = "opc", label = "Measurements", choices = c("heart_rate","oxygen_saturation")),
```

The code above works great, the table suddenly displays data again and it filters correctly. I just don't get it! The sliderInput works great as well. The data set has been included as an enviroment variable.
[image]

This are the two different outputs (first picture with written values, second picture using levels(data$measurement)):
[image]

[image]

Why is this happening to me?!

Comment: But you are sure that `measurement` is a factor? Outside the app, in the console when you run `levels(data$measurement)` you are not getting `NULL`, right?

Comment: What is your `data` object?  Can you post some sample data records?

Comment: Try `unique(data$measurement)` instead, that might work.